# How to split XML in windows phone 7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

How i can split the XML?  I am using This code

```
public static String insertNewMsg(String aMsg, String newMsgXML)
{
    String retXML = null;
    //int size = aMsg.s
    String[] strParts = aMsg.Split("</messages>");
    if (strParts.Length >= 0)
    {
        retXML = strParts[0] + newMsgXML + "</messages>";
    }
    return retXML;
}
```

I want to Split when the end tag reaches(i.e ("?messages"))

Comment: Can you post an example of your xml? And try to explain better what you want to do

Comment: Note that `if (strParts.Length >= 0)` will *always* either be true or throw a `NullReferenceException` - there's no such thing as an array with a negative number of elements.

Comment: retXML = "<messages><msg><msg_time>" + msg_time + "</msg_time><msg_id>"
    + l_msg_id + "</msg_id><from_id>" + from_id
    + "</from_id><avatar>" + Avatar
    + "</avatar><sender_name>" + sender_name
    + "</sender_name><to_id>" + to_id + "</to_id><msg_text>" + msg_text
    + "</msg_text><picture_key>" + picture_key
    + "</picture_key><save_id>" + sID + "</save_id><m_type>"
    + m_type + "</m_type></msg></messages>";

  return retXML;when end tag reach i want to split("/mesages")

Comment: You can edit your own questions. Do this instead of posting comments. And start reading what people are telling you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to handle XML with string operations. Use XML libraries - Windows Phone 7 supports LINQ to XML, which will make your life a *lot* easier.

You haven't said what you're trying to do, but it's likely to be very straightforward using LINQ to XML.

EDIT: Your now-deleted comment showed that you were building the original XML using string concatenation. *Please* don't do that. It's the XML equivalent of building a SQL query by including user values in the SQL itself instead of using a parameterized query - and it's just as dangerous. LINQ to XML is a lovely library, well supported in Windows Phone 7 - so use it whenever you want to perform *any* XML operations - creating, parsing, or manipulating.

Comment: retXML = "<messages><msg><msg_time>" + msg_time + "</msg_time><msg_id>"
    + l_msg_id + "</msg_id><from_id>" + from_id
    + "</from_id><avatar>" + Avatar
    + "</avatar><sender_name>" + sender_name
    + "</sender_name><to_id>" + to_id + "</to_id><msg_text>" + msg_text
    + "</msg_text><picture_key>" + picture_key
    + "</picture_key><save_id>" + sID + "</save_id><m_type>"
    + m_type + "</m_type></msg></messages>";

  return retXML;when end tag reach i want to split("/mesages").

Comment: @SumeshMohanK: It's not clear why you posted that code, but see my edit - *don't* do this. It's still not clear what you're trying to achieve, either. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

In WP7, complex XML files can be easily handled by the LINQ than the string operations,
It may XML to LINQ or LINQ to XML.

You can get detail information about the LINQ and samples here

- http://jesseliberty.com/2011/02/15/linq-to-xml/
- http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/android-to-wp7-chapter-7-xml-parsing-in-windows-phone-7-and-android#h2Section0